# Custom ggplot2 geom comprised of many geom_polygons

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data frames that are created from parameterized functions, then plotted together on a `ggplot` object via `geom_polygon()`. For example, say I have a circle defined by

```r
create_circle <- function(center = c(0, 0),
                          npoints = 1000,
                          r = 1,
                          start = 0,
                          end = 2) {
  pts <- seq(start * pi, end * pi, length.out = npoints)
  circle_coords <- data.frame(
    x = center[1] + (r * cos(pts)),
    y = center[2] + (r * sin(pts))
  )

  return(circle_coords)
}
```

and a function to draw a square by

```r
create_square <- function(side_length, center = c(0, 0)) {
  square_coords <- data.frame(
    x = c(
      center[1] - (side_length / 2),
      center[1] + (side_length / 2),
      center[1] + (side_length / 2),
      center[1] - (side_length / 2),
      center[1] - (side_length / 2)
    ),
    y = c(
      center[2] - (side_length / 2),
      center[2] - (side_length / 2),
      center[2] + (side_length / 2),
      center[2] + (side_length / 2),
      center[2] - (side_length / 2)
    )
  )      
  
  return(square_coords)
}
```

I know I can use the code below to generate the following graphic, which works, but I'd like to turn these into `geom`s that can take the parameters of each shape and produce a `ggproto` object so I can call these in additional contexts. Here's the examples:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# define the two shapes with appropriate parameters
circle <- create_circle(r = 1)
square <- create_square(side_length = 2)

# draw the plot
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(
    data = circle,
    aes(x, y),
    fill = "#ffffff00",
    color = "#ff552e"
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = square,
    aes(x, y),
    fill = "#ffffff00",
    color = "#13294b"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: circle inside of square]

```r
circle <- create_circle(r = 0.5, center = c(1, 1))
square <- create_square(side_length = 1, center = c(-1, -1))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(
    data = circle,
    aes(x, y),
    fill = "#ffffff00",
    color = "#ff552e"
  ) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = square,
    aes(x, y),
    fill = "#ffffff00",
    color = "#13294b"
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: circle outside of square]

Essentially, what I'm wondering if it's possible to do is to create a custom `ggproto` object that takes parameterized `geom_polygons()` and combines them to serve as plotting backgrounds so that they may be called together. Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!